# ImportError on only one of my two identical sites

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I have two websites, that are "almost" clones of one another. Well, in fact, they're supposed to be full clones (both have the same source code & config, point to the same database).

I am able to work with one of these sites without any problems, yet I'm getting [this error](https://gist.github.com/890355) when accessing the other one. There must be some configuration difference between them causing this problem, but as far as I could tell their configuration is identical (up to the folder/application names and path).

They are located at ~/sites/meta-d3c and ~/sites/beta-meta-d3c.

As an example, here are a few of their configs:

**Meta**

- [OSGI](https://gist.github.com/890365)
- [Apache Conf](https://gist.github.com/890371) (under sites-available)

**Beta**

- [OSGI](https://gist.github.com/890361)
- [Apache Conf](https://gist.github.com/890373)

If there are more relevant configs, please let me know and I'll attach.
As an experiment, I'll happily pay 2 [BitCoins](http://ripper234.com/tag/bitcoin/) for anyone posting a good solution.

Comment: I think your error link is wrong.  Perhaps it should the [this](https://gist.github.com/890355) instead?

Comment: It looks like you are using a settings_local.py file?  That file exists for beta?

Comment: @dgel - thanks, too much gists. The problem was indeed a missing settings_local, I copied from _dist and adjusted permissions, and it worked! Do you want those 2 BitCoins? (Regardless, put this up as an answer and I'll accept)

Comment: Sure, but I just installed it. Fascinating. Is it safe to post my receiving address here?

Comment: +1 the comment and +1 the question because of an interesting read about bitcoins =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a `settings_local.py` that must be being imported by your settings.